# Configuring AmazonLinux AMI instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, chef-infra, puppet, ec2-ami

I am trying to setup an AMI such that, when booted it will auto configure itself with a defined "configuration" somewhere on a server. I came across Chef and Puppet. Considering Puppet, I was able to run though their examples but couldn't see one for auto configuration from master. I found out that Puppet Enterprise is not supported on "Amazon Linux". Team chose Amazon Linux and would like keep that instead of going to other OS just because one tool doesn't support it. Can someone please give me some idea about how I could achieve this? (I am trying to stay away from home grown shell scripts over a good industry adopted tool for maintainability)

Answer (score 1):

What I have done in the past is to copy /etc/rc.local to /etc/rc.local.orig, and then configure /etc/rc.local to kick off a puppet run and then pave over itself.

/etc/rc.local:

```
#!/bin/bash
##
#add pre-puppeting stuff here, I add the hostname in "User-data" when creating the VM so I can set the hostname before checking in
##
/usr/bin/puppet agent --test
/bin/cp -f /etc/rc.local.orig /etc/rc.local
/sbin/init 6
```

Answer (score 0):

AWS CloudFormation is one of Amazon's recommended ways to provision servers (and other cloud resources, too). You declare all the resources you need in a JSON file, and specify how to provision each server by declaring packages to install, services to run, files to create, and commands to run when the server is created. See the [user guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/Welcome.html) for more information. I also wrote a couple of [blog posts](http://blog.engelke.com/2012/12/28/provisioning-a-server-with-cloudformation/) about getting started with it.